# How could I achieve an iOS high detailed level design for a platformer?

Tags: architecture, ios, spritekit

I'm seeing a lot of games that use a predefined and repeating set of tiles for their level (like FlappyBird or the Super Mario game series).

I'm a graphics designer so I would like to create levels with a *much higher* level of details for the game levels. I'm thinking about games such as `Limbo` (screenshot at the end of the post) or `BadLand`.

I thought about designing the whole level in one big  high detailed image which could reach to 30k pixels in width, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

How should I structure my game to achieve that level of detail?

I'm using sprite-kit.

[image]

Comment: You should check out [this interview](http://artistryingames.com/leos-fortune-interview-lead-designer-anders-heidenberg/) with Anders Hejdenberg, Lead Designer of Leo's Fortune - a game which has very high level of detail and what custom tech is required to achieve such a feat.

Comment: From the above link: "The largest canvas in the game is for level 18, which is 57k by 14k pixels."

Comment: I cut the large level image into small pieces and adding them into a parent node and it worked very fine , but I assume after high details in the game frames are gonna be created slower so separates would appear !